# IIS AppCmd - Cannot create/configure virtual directory under application

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-8, windows-server, appcmd

I have a web application hosted in IIS server. I want to add a virtual directory to this web application. This virtual directory should be pointing to folder in a network file share. Problem is I am not able to use appcmd  to create this virtual directory.

This is the structure of the application.

```
[ ] MySite  (IIS Site)
 |
 +---[ ] MyApplication  (Application)
      |  
      +----[ ] MyVirtualDirectory  (Virtual Directory)   <--*** I Want to create this VDIR***
```

I am trying to do this in powershell so this is what I have so far.

```
$site = "MySite"
$app = "MyApplication"
$path = "MyVirtualDirectory"
$physicalpath = "\\10.10.10.10\Path\To\Share\Folder"
$username = "myusername"
$password = "mySuperSecurePassword" 

# adding vdir
# This works fine
appcmd add vdir /app.name:"$($site)/" /path:"/$($app)/$($path)" /physicalPath:$physicalpath

# setting network credentials 
# This FAILS with error ERROR (message:Must use exact identifer for VDIR object with verb SET.)
appcmd set vdir /vdir.name:"$($site)/$($app)/$($path)" /userName:"$username" /password:"$password"
```

The last command above fails with this error "**ERROR (message:Must use exact identifer for VDIR object with verb SET.)**"

I can see the virtual directory in IIS UI and using "appcmd list vdir". But trying to interact with it from there gives a pop-up notification saysing the virtual directory does not exists

[image: The virtual directory does not exist.]

I cannot delete the virtual directory using appcmd as well.

```
appcmd delete vdir "MySite/MyApplication/MyVirtualDirectory"
ERROR ( message:Must use exact identifer for VDIR object with verb DELETE. )
```

The only way get back to previous state is editing applicationHost.config.

How can I create virtual network and set network credentials to the file share in this case? I would also like to know if there is a way to delete that virtual directory.

**Side Note**

I have noticed however that similar command works if I was creating virtual directory under Site(Not Application).

eg.

```
[ ] MySite  (IIS Site)
 |  
 +----[ ] MyVirtualDirectory  (Virtual Directory)   <--*** To Create this VDIR***
```

following powershell script works

```
$site = "MySite"
$path = "MyVirtualDirectory"
$physicalpath = "\\10.10.10.10\Path\To\Share\Folder"
$username = "myusername"
$password = "mySuperSecurePassword" 

# This works fine
appcmd add vdir /app.name:"$($site)/" /path:"/$($path)" /physicalPath:$physicalpath

# This works fine too.
appcmd set vdir /vdir.name:"$($site)/$($path)" /userName:"$username" /password:"$password"
```

Comment: Have you tried signing into the web server as 'myusername', and confirming that you have access to \\10.10.10.10\Path\To\Share\Folder ? Keep in mind that you'll need to grant access to the App Pool user, not just the vDir. Create an Application Pool if you don't have one and set the same credentials there, then assign the app pool to the application/VDir.

Comment: Yes, i have tries that. The folder has correct permissions. Just to be clear. I am able to add this from iis ui and it works without issue. Its just that appcmd fails here.

Comment: i am also having the exact same issue.  I began to have this problem trying to use azure pipelines to push our website release to a VM.  It creates a virtual directory two or three times then just randomly fails and then works for awhile again and is very random.    executing appcmd from the cmd prompt directly    I can see a list of virtual directories on the server and i can list them but cannot delete them.   it says "must use exact identifer for vdir object with verb delete" even though i am providing the exact name.

Comment: @Matt its been a while since I tackled this issue. But I think I solved this issue by using powershell command instead. Not sure powershell is a option for you or not. 

I ended up using Set-WebConfigurationProperty (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/set-webconfigurationproperty?view=win10-ps) 

see example here.
https://www.jasonholden.com/use-powershell-to-add-iis-virtual-directory-with-login-connect-as/

Answer (score 0):

To do this:

You need to use the following command:

```
appcmd add vdir /app.name:"$($site)/$($app)" /path:"/$($path)" /physicalPath:$physicalpath
```

The app name must point to the full (virtual) path of the application